# Can anyone delete an answer so that it is invisible even for users with more than 10k reputation?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, moderators

In this question ( [MVC 3 detached entity saving related children properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7746889/270591) ) and my answer the user who asked the question complained and argued that I had deleted other answers and even his own answer. I cannot delete answers, except my own, so I'm wondering if anyone else, a moderator for example, deleted other answers. But because I (with >10k reputation) can't see any deleted answers in this question I'm wondering if it is possible to delete answers in a way that they are invisible to me.

He wrote his complaint in a comment below my answer and probably voted down since he was apparently quite angry. He said that he had provided code in his own answer which was almost the same like the code linked in my answer. I replied to his comment in my own comment emphasizing my innocence, but both comments are deleted now. He said he would flag my answer and the result of the attracted moderator attention was probably that the comments have been deleted without further notice (not a good moderator action in my opinion). I wrote a summary in a comment under his question, since I really don't like to be suspected that I manipulate question/answers to my own benefit.

Comment: There are no deleted answers on that question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In very, very rare cases, the dev team is able to completely eradicate a post to leave no trace, not even for 10k users. I don't think this has truly been exercised since the Boat Programming incident, however, so **for all general intents and purposes, no one can delete a post in such a fashion that no one can see it**.

As [noted by ChrisF](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114513/can-anyone-delete-an-answer-so-that-it-is-invisible-even-for-users-with-more-tha#comment-298020), there aren't any deleted answers on that question. The user in question only has one deleted answer from a question over a month ago.

Comment: Thanks! What was the "Boat Programming incident"?

Comment: @Slauma There was a question which was done basically to test the limits of topicality on the site by being as inanely tangential to programming as possible. Sorta as a demonstration of questions whose only tie to being on-topic on the site were the words "as a programmer" in the title. It was basically asking "I'm planning to spend the rest of my days on a boat, what do I need to prepare in order to continue my programming work at sea?" For whatever reason, it was completely obliterated, rather than a standard deletion.

Comment: The user in question seems to be sure that there were more answers than mine, and one was his own answer (see comments to the linked question). I recommended to describe this here on meta as a possible bug.